Lack of the name Hashem Tzevaot in the Torah
There is a dispute on Shevuot 35 whereby, according to one opinion, Tzevaot is one of the Divine Names that may not be erased. Although Hashem Tzevaot appears frequently in various haftarot and prayers, I've recently discovered in a concordance that there is no such Divine Name in the Torah. How come? Because it first occurs in the Book of Samuel, I've tried to connect it to the establishment of the Jewish kingdom, but it's just a mere speculation, so I'd appreciate any well-sourced answer!

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/120383/what-might-g-ds-self-identification-as-the-ruler-of-armies-be-intended-to-exp?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment414174_120391

Berachot 31b:

מיום שברא הקדוש ברוך הוא את עולמו, לא היה אדם שקראו להקדוש ברוך הוא
״צבאות״, עד שבאתה חנה וקראתו ״צבאות״
From the day that the Holy One, Blessed be He, created His world,
there was no person who called the Holy One, Blessed be He, Lord of
Hosts until Hannah came and called Him Lord of Hosts.

According to this gemara, Chana invoked this name in order to make a point, i.e. Hashem, you have צבאות, legions, is it so much to ask for just one child? The pshat of this implies that this is the way this Name should be used, and until this moment, nobody had needed to (or figure out how to) use it this way:

משל למה הדבר דומה — למלך בשר ודם שעשה סעודה לעבדיו. בא עני אחד ועמד על
הפתח, אמר להם: תנו לי פרוסה אחת! ולא השגיחו עליו. דחק ונכנס אצל המלך.
אמר לו: אדוני המלך, מכל סעודה שעשית קשה בעיניך ליתן לי פרוסה אחת?!
[The Gemara suggests] a parable: To what is this similar? [It is similar
to] a flesh and blood king who made a feast for his servants. A poor
person came and stood at the door. He said to them: Give me one slice
of bread! And they paid him no attention. He pushed and entered before
the king. He said to him: My lord, the King, from this entire feast
that you have prepared, is it so difficult in your eyes to give me a
single slice [of bread]? [Steinsaltz translation, and commentary in square brackets]

The Ben Yehoyada on this piece brings the Chida's "Chomat Anach", who gives a Kabbalistic reason why this name was only used for the first time by Sefer Shmuel. To cut to the chase, a bat kol informed Chana that Shmuel would rectify something spiritually, and this rectification was what facilitated Hashem's Name צבאות to be used.
Rabbi Yosef Chayim Z'tl also explains the difference between Hashem Tzvakot and Elokim Tzvakot, if you want to go and look there, but the answer is Kabbalistic, so I won't put it in this answer.

It is interesting that Shmuel, the product of this tefilah, is said to be equivalent to Moshe (Netzach) and Aharon (Hod), who are associated with the names Havaya Tzevaos and Elokim Tzevaos respectively.

Also interesting is the fact that we Shmuel is called ״בקוראי שמו״, perhaps hinting at the new name revealed through Shmuel.

https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Numbers.16.7.1

@Yø-cRo ah, you were quoting Rashi, not R' Chayim. Not necessarily a stira? Either way, yes, very interesting and amazing connection, thank you
